# Multiple transaction manager with multiple session factories

Tags: spring, transactions

My basic requirement to have multiple sessionFactory objects to point two different schema ( this is logical grouping, each logical group have multiple schema in it), so here is configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1" />
<transactionManager1>
  <sessionFactory1>
</transactionManager1>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2" />
<transactionManager2>
  <sessionFactory2>
</transactionManager2>
```

now I created Dao class which has save method

```
@Transactional
public void save(Object){
   sessionFactory2.getCurrentSession().save(object);
}
```

this code is working fine, but my question is that, Which transaction manager will be picked by @Transactional annotation?

or there a way to print it in log?

Comment: Please also suggest If I can change logic of @transactional annotation.

Comment: In your case `transactionManager2`... Having multiple `<tx:annotation-driven />` elements has no sense and is pretty useless. The last one is the one that will be effective. And as you specify a specific `transaction-manager` that is the one that will be used by default if no explicit one is defined in the `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the (pseudo) configuration you posted is also the order in which you have it defined in your configuration then always the `transactionManager2` will be used.

Defining multiple `<tx:annotation-driven />` elements has no use. With this element you indicate that you want to use annotation driven transactions and that you want to use the given `transaction-manager` as the default transaction manager.

In your case you have defined 2 and the last one will be the one that is the effective one.

When using multiple transaction managers you MUST specify in the `@Transactional` annotation which transaction manager to use for that particular transactional method.

So you need to specify either `@Transactional("transactionManager1")` or `@Transactional("transactionManager2")` depending on which one you see as the default one.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, now I can imagine background process. but after going through your answer, again two questions comes in my mind: 1. do we have any process where I can select transaction manager dynamically when annotation is getting applied? 2. what is the use of sessionFactory instance which we are setting into transaction manager. because in this case, it may happen that, transactionManager2 is getting applied while saving entity with sessionFactory1, where there is no any relation with sessionFactory1 and transactionManager2.

Answer (score 0):

yuo can specify the transacion manager to you by passing its name in the annotation
For example:

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager2")
public void save(Object){
   sessionFactory2.getCurrentSession().save(object);
}
```

You can find more details here http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

I hope it's useful

Angelo